# How can I import CSV file into a PostgreSQL based on condition

Tags: files, csv, postgresql

I have CSV file that contains records for all the provinces (chm, mk ...).

```
file.csv:
time,language,province,longitude,latitude
number  en  chm number  number  
number  en  mk  number  number
```

Structure of my PostgreSQL db looks like this:

```
├── chm (schema)
|   └── cvs (table)
├── mk (schema)
|   └── cvs (table)
:
└── last_province
```

I would like to import file.csv in PostgreSQL that records fit to same `Schema/Province`.

```
├── chm (schema)
|   └── cvs (table)
|       ├── time: number (column1)
|       ├── language: en (column2)
|       ├── province: chm (column3)
|       ├── longitude: number (column4)
|       └── latitude: number (column5)
├── mk (schema)
|   └── cvs (table)
|       ├── time: number (column1)
|       ├── language: en (column2)
|       ├── province: chm (column3)
|       ├── longitude: number (column4)
|       └── latitude: number (column5)
:
└── last_province
```

What is the easiest way to accomplish that?

**Note:**

I know that I can import data with command `copy` but I only know how to copy it to a specific schema.

```
\copy chm.cvs(time,language,province,longitude,latitude) FROM '/home/Desktop/data/file.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Can I somehow make some kind of condition which would be equal to

```
WHERE province = 'chm'
```

Comment: Option 1: use `grep` or `awk` to split your CSV file into different files and `copy` them in individually.  Option 2: `copy` the data into a _temporary_ table and then `insert into ... select from... where...` to put the results into the target tables.